# Self added text to columns based on column index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Input Table:[Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNmYh.png)

Desired Output : [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQcM8.png)

I want to add 'A,B,C.....' in columns as you are seeing in output. It should be governed from no. of columns. As columns increases from 2 to 3 than in 3rd column 'C' should be added automatically. Please suggest how can we approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
   df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: chr(ord('A')+i) + str(int(x)) if not pd.isna(x) else x)
```

Comment: This is working perfectly for me. Only one problem is coming for second and third column value, it is showing B1.0,B2.0,B3.0 instead of B1,B2,B3. Same for third columns. Integers are reflecting into float value. please suggest

Comment: Just edited, I changed to int before changing to string, can you see if it works now? @VinitSharma

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the alphabet you can use `string` library:

```
import string 
chars = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
```

I don't which is the format of your input file. Let's assume that you have loaded it in someway and organized it with columns. For example if your input file is a text file you can use:

```
import numpy
cols = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
```

use `unpack=True` your data will be loaded by column, so `cols` is a list of columns.
Now let's implement the core of your code:

```
from functools import partial
def add_char(x_i, c_i):
    return c_i+str(x_i)

outs = []
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    add_char_i = partial(add_char, c_i=chars[i])
    out = list(map(add_char_p, col))
    outs.append(out)

outs = np.column_stack(outs)
```